# How to loop over a nested object- javascript

Tags: javascript

So I have this array with nested objects and I want to loop over that with an `forEach()` method. In the end I would love to have 4 sentences that look like that:

- Jelly donuts cost $1.22 each
- Chocolate donuts cost $2.45 each
- Cider donuts cost $1.59 each
- Boston Cream donuts cost $5.99 each

I thought I need an inner loop to address the individual items but I am not so sure any more. I really appreciate your help. Here is my code so far:

```
var donuts = [
  { type: "Jelly", cost: 1.22 },
  { type: "Chocolate", cost: 2.45 },
  { type: "Cider", cost: 1.59 },
  { type: "Boston Cream", cost: 5.99 }
];

donuts.forEach(function(elem) {
  for (i=0; i<elem.length; i++) {
    let type = donuts[i].type
    let cost = donuts[i].cost
    console.log(type + " donuts cost $" + cost + " each");  
  }
});
```

Comment: Want to display the price?

Comment: The function you pass to `donuts.forEach()` is called four times, getting passed each array element as argument in turn. So `elem` will be `{ type: "Jelly", cost: 1.22 }` the first time, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

forEach() calls a provided callback function once for each element in an array. Here donuts is array of javascript object representing individual donut.

```js
var donuts = [{
        type: "Jelly",
        cost: 1.22
    },
    {
        type: "Chocolate",
        cost: 2.45
    },
    {
        type: "Cider",
        cost: 1.59
    },
    {
        type: "Boston Cream",
        cost: 5.99
    }
];

donuts.forEach(function(donut) {

    console.log(donut.type + " donuts cost $" + donut.cost + " each");
});
```

Comment: Add some explanatory text, rename the argument from `e` to `donut`, turn the code into a snippet (`<>` button) and you have my upvote :)